# How to fix build.gradle error in my nativescript app

Tags: android, angular, nativescript

I am using nativescript for my mobile app and when I run `"tns run android"`, after a few minutes I receive the follow error:

```
Build file 'C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\nativescript-mobile-app\platforms\android\app\build.gradle' line: 598
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
Could not GET 'https://dl.bintray.com/triniwiz/maven/com/github/triniwiz/fancycamera/3.0.0-alpha16/fancycamera-3.0.0-alpha16.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
```

I would like to know how do I go about fixing it. This package is not in my `package.json` file

Comment: Are you using any NativeScript plugins?